# Finding $f(0)$, $f'(0)$, $f''(0)$ and $f'''(0)$ of $T_2(x) = 5-7x+8x^2$ (Taylor Polynomial)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Given that $f(x)$ is a function approximated near $x=0$ by the second degree Taylor polynomial given below, I am asked to find $f(0)$, $f'(0)$, $f''(0)$ and $f'''(0)$

$$T_2(x) = 5-7x+8x^2$$

My question is: Its pretty straightforward that $f(0) = 5$, $f'(0) = -7$ and $f''(0) = 16$ but what should be the value of $f'''(0)$? Should it be zero?

Comment: The polynomial $5-7x+8x^2 + ax^3$ has the second degree Taylor approximation that you've given for any $a\in \Bbb R$. If the $_2$ in $T_2$ means that you have a second degree approximation, then there is no way you can tell what $f'''(x)$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no answer !

Examples: Let $f(x) = 5-7x+8x^2+6x^3$ or $f(x) = 5-7x+8x^2+12x^3$ or $f(x) = 5-7x+8x^2-6x^3$ .

In all these cases we have $T_2(x) = 5-7x+8x^2$